# Prevent McAfee Security Scan Plus from installing - ever

Tags: windows-7, malware, anti-virus, hosts-file

Whenever Flash updates, some colleague or friend keeps pressing OK, and without noticing, McAfee Security Scan Plus is installed (and it happened to me several times as well). Then, after a while, a screen pops up, and I get questions from those friends who are worried that their computer is at risk. I've seen this happen so many times, and I cannot ignore it, only remove it once again.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, no matter if it's downloaded or not? Can I prevent it from downloading somehow? If it's installed, can I prevent it from running? Using the hosts file, marking it as malware in the antivirus program (which can be any antivirus program, but most likely MS Security Essentials, Avast or Kaspersky but of course not Norton or McAfee), or any other method?

I want to get rid of it and I don't want to to deal with it ever again!!!

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Just a suggestion. Instead of using Adobe to download flash, ask your friends to try using a site like http://www.filehippo.com/ to download the updates. FileHippo even has an update checker which will let you periodically check for updates.

Comment: Ninite.com has the same functionality as @Ganesh R suggested, it would also be worth a look. Run the installer again to update.